# What is the general expression for the area bounded by these lines?

Tags: integration, geometry

Consider 5 lines. The verticals $x=0$ and $x=1$, the horizontals $y=0$ and $y=1$ and the diagonal $p y +(1-p)x =k$ where $p$ and $k$ are both constants between 0 and 1. I am trying to find the area bounded by these five lines. In particular, I am wondering if there is a general expression for this area for any values of $p$ and $k$.

Some more details about my attempt:

The $y$ intercept of the diagonal line is $k/p$ and the $x$ intercept is $k/(1-p)$. Thus, depending on the values of $k$ and $p$, the area to be found can be a five-sided shape (when both $k/p$ and $k/(1-p)$ are less than 1), triangular (when both $k/p$ and $k/(1-p)$ are greater than 1) or quadrilateral (when the $y$-intercept is greater than 1 and the $x$-intercept is less than 1). While I would be happy finding the area for any given $k$ and $p$, I am wondering if it is possible to find a general expression, as the procedure I used to find the area in each case is different.

In terms of inequalities, I am interested in the area $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$ and $p y +(1-p)x >k$

Comment: I think there is some ambiguity as to which part of the square you want to measure when the diagonal line passes through $y=1$ at some $x \in (0,1)$, through $x=1$ at some $y \in (0,1)$, through $y=0$ at some $x>1$ and through $x=0$ at some $y>1$. In this case the square is split into a triangle and a pentagon. Which one do you want? It sounded from your casework like you want the triangle. I guess the general pattern is you want the part of the square above the line?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and sorry for the ambiguity. I have edited the question to  describe the area in terms of inequalities which hopefully clarifies things

Comment: Then the height of a vertical slice of the region is either $1$ or $1-(k-(1-p)x)/p$ whichever is smaller. So you integrate the minimum of those two from 0 to 1. To do that explicitly you need to solve the inequality $1-(k-(1-p)x)/p<1$ for $x$.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't I have to integrate the minimum of those two from 0 to the minimum of either 1 or the x-intercept?

Comment: Why would you cut the region off at the x intercept? If the x intercept is between 0 and 1 then you want to include the entire rectangle to the right of it, don't you?

Comment: Yes, if the x-intercept is between 0 and 1, I would want to include it. But if the x-intercept is greater than 1, I would want to integrating when I reach 1. I think...

Comment: The mistake I made is that you need to interpret an apparent negative height as being zero. Or in other words the height of a slice is $\max \{ 0,\min \{ 1,1-(k-(1-p)x)/p \} \}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $q=1-p$. The diagonal line becomes $py+qx = k$, where $0<p,q,k<1$.

I find it easier to first consider the triangular intersection $R_1$ formed by
$$R_1: (0<x) \wedge (0<y)\wedge (py + qx < k)$$
The three vertices are $\left(0,\frac kp\right)$, $(0,0)$, $\left(\frac{k}{q}, 0\right)$, so the area of this triangle is $\frac{k^2}{2pq}$.

Intersect $R_1$ with $x<1$ to form $R_2$:
$$R_2: (0<x<1) \wedge (0<y)\wedge (py + qx < k)$$
The diagonal crosses $x=1$ at $\left(1, \frac{k-q}{p}\right)$. If $k>q$, then this step will remove a triangular region, which has vertices $\left(1, \frac{k-q}{p}\right)$, $(1,0)$, $\left(\frac{k}{q}, 0\right)$ and area $\frac{(k-q)^2}{2pq}$.

Intersect $R_2$ with $y<1$ to form $R_3$:
$$R_3: (0<x<1) \wedge (0<y<1)\wedge (py + qx < k)$$
The diagonal crosses $y=1$ at $\left(\frac{k-p}{q}, 1\right)$. If $k>p$, then this step will remove a triangular region, which has vertices $\left(0, \frac{k}{p}\right)$, $(0, 1)$, $\left(\frac{k-p}{q}, 1\right)$ and area $\frac{(k-p)^2}{2pq}$.

Considering all cases of $k$ and $p$, the area of $R_3$ can be written using the $\max$ function as

$$\begin{align*}
\text{Area of $R_3$}
&= \frac{k^2}{2pq} - \frac{[\max(0,k-q)]^2}{2pq} - \frac{[\max(0, k-p)]^2}{2pq}\\
&= \frac{k^2-[\max(0,k-q)]^2-[\max(0, k-p)]^2}{2pq}\\
&= \frac{k^2-[\max(q,k)-q]^2-[\max(p, k)-p]^2}{2pq}\\
\end{align*}$$

The required area from the question is then

$$R_4: (0<x<1) \wedge (0<y<1) \wedge (py + (1-p)x>k)\\
\begin{align*}
\text{Area of $R_4$}
&= 1-\frac{k^2-[\max(q,k)-q]^2-[\max(p, k)-p]^2}{2pq}\\
&= 1-\frac{k^2-[\max(1-p,k)-(1-p)]^2-[\max(p, k)-p]^2}{2p(1-p)}\\
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $q=1-p$. The diagonal line becomes $py+qx=k$, where $0<p,q,k<1$.

The diagonal crosses $y=1$ at $\left(\frac{k-p}q,1\right)$, and crosses $x=1$ at $\left(1, \frac{k-q}p\right)$.

Define the following vertices related to the required polygon.

$$\begin{align*}
P_1 &= (1,1)\\
P_2 &= \left(\max\left(0, \frac{k-p}q\right),1\right) = \left(\frac{\max(0,k-p)}q,1\right)\\
P_3 &= \left(0, \frac kp\right)\\
P_4 &= \left(\frac kq, 0\right)\\
P_5 &= \left(1, \max\left(0, \frac{k-q}p\right)\right) = \left(1, \frac{\max(0,k-q)}p\right)\\
P_6 &= P_1
\end{align*}$$

$P_3$ and/or $P_4$ may be outside the required polygon, but in such cases their adjacent edges would overlap and so would not change the area.

By the shoelace formula, the area inside the polygon with vertices $P_1,\ldots, P_5$ is

$$\begin{align*}
\text{Area}
&= \frac12 \begin{vmatrix}
1 & \frac{\max(0,k-p)}q & 0 & \frac{k}q & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & \frac{k}p & 0 & \frac{\max(0,k-q)}p & 1
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \frac1{2pq} \begin{vmatrix}
q & \max(0,k-p) & 0 & k & q & q\\
p & p & k & 0 & \max(0,k-q) & p
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \frac1{2pq} \left[qp + k\max(0,k-p) + 0 + k\max(0,k-q) + qp - p\max(0,k-p) -0- k^2 - 0 - q\max(0,k-q)\right]\\
&= \frac1{2pq} \left[2pq + (k-p)\max(0,k-p) + (k-q)\max(0,k-q) - k^2\right]\\
&= 1-\frac{k^2 - [\max(0,k-p)]^2 - [\max(0,k-q)]^2}{2pq}\\
&= 1-\frac{k^2 - [\max(0,k-p)]^2 - [\max(0,k+p-1)]^2}{2p(1-p)}\\
\end{align*}$$